# Python- TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Tags: python, pandas, csv, error-handling, time-series

I am writing this code to convert the column in a specific csv file and then convert it to human readable time. However, it works only if I specified one data value and when I try to convert the whole column it shows this error:
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

```
import pandas as pd 
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
n=0
file_path= askopenfilename(filetypes=(("CSV File","*.csv"),("All files","*.*")))
print(file_path)
selected_File = pd.read_csv(file_path)
print(selected_File.iloc[:,0])
dtime=datetime.fromtimestamp(selected_File.iloc[:,0])
print(type(dtime))
initial_date="1/1/1900 0:00:00"
i_date= datetime.strptime(initial_date,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
correct_date=i_date+timedelta(days=selected_File.iloc[:,0])
print(correct_date)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the Python standard library function `datetime.fromtimestamp` which expects an integer or something like it.  You are passing a Series from Pandas, which it has no idea what to do with.

If you want to apply a function for every element in a series, you need to use the [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html?highlight=series%20apply#pandas.Series.apply) method.  E.g.,

```
selected_File.iloc[0,:].apply(datetime.fromtimestamp)
```

This is assuming that every column in your data contains integers representing timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas inbuilt function 'to_datetime' also.

Check [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)